# woocommerce увеличить скорость загрузки категории

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, оптимизация-сайтов

В основной категории woo 720 товаров плюс фильтры. Но при загрузке категории сайт сильно тормозит пока выгрузит все товары. Есть какая-то возможность выгружать только первую страницу с пагинацией например 16 товаров, следующие 16 только при обращении к следующей странице?

Comment: По умолчанию ву выводит товары с пагинацей, ищите в теме, где вы ее отключили. Например в /wp-admin/options-reading.php